# which is better friendly url among the these?

Tags: url, friendly-url

I want to know which of the following urls is best to use:

```
http://www.website.com/index.php?i=123
http://www.website.com/i123/item-name/
http://www.website.com/item-name/i123/
http://www.website.com/i123-item-name.htm
http://www.website.com/i/123-item-name.htm
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prefer `http://www.website.com/i123/item-name/`, due to the fact that you can still parse `http://www.website.com/i123/` easily if someone omits the name, and it's clear what is the name and what is not.

Comment: 2nded. Although leaving out the ID altogether looks even nicer if you can enforce unique names.

Comment: Looks nicer, but hurts those who'd prefer to have a shorter url (without having to use a service like tinyurl).

Answer (score 1):

Common sense votes for `http://www.website.com/i123/item-name/' ... we have base for the ID and name if needed for storing or posting a link. the htm and ? links are a pain for the eye ;)

P.S. And for heavens sake `html` not `htm`!

Comment: Completely by accident, this is the schema used by SO :)